# while playing can change the sound output?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Recently I started with Android.

I'm trying to do a small example to understand how the sound output with android.

To this I build me a program that plays an mp3 file, and while this playing can change the sound output to:

- Internal Speaker
- External Speaker
- Headset
- Earpiece

Is this possible?

I have part of the code done, but do not know how to jump from a sound output to another.

public class TestAudioActivity extends Activity {

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private ImageButton playButton;
private ImageButton pauseButton;
private ImageButton stopButton;
AudioManager audioManager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initializeMediaPlayer();

    playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    pauseButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
    stopButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) 
                mediaPlayer.start();
            else
                initializeMediaPlayer();
        }
    });

    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /** if (mediaPlayer != null) 
                 mediaPlayer.pause(); */
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);

        }
    });

    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    });

}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://server3.pianosociety.com/protected/bach-bwv772-stahlbrand.mp3");
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // Mostramos mensaje en caso de error.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL no encontrada", 2000);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: are you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I have never played with media activities yet, but yes you can change your sound output while playing for example you can use

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: Hi Pedro, I added the code that you sent but does not work when running the application code out, and stop the execution.